# How to fix bundler module resolution issue without deleting/installing npm packages?

Tags: react-native, agora.io, metro-bundler

Goal: successfully build & bundle react native project using `react-native-agora` v3.0.1-rc.4, while preserving npm packages that i have edited.

I was told to try updating to this version by agora support staff. after a bunch of errors and managing them, I come to another issue. the project now builds, but won't successfully bundle. bundle process fails (on iOS, haven't tried android yet):

```
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `./AgoraView.native` from `node_modules/react-native-agora/lib/index.js`: 

None of these files exist:
  * node_modules/react-native-agora/lib/AgoraView.native(.native|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  * node_modules/react-native-agora/lib/AgoraView.native/index(.native|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
```

RN v0.61.5

Im not sure why its trying to resolve `./AgoraView.native`. As I dont have it explicitly referenced anywhere.

So far ive tried:

- `npm cache clean --force`
- uninstalling and reinstalling `react-native-agora`
- `pod install`
- cleaning build folder and rebuilding

How to resolve?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to delete node_modules and re-install it and clean build folder of iOS. I think it cached the last version of react-native-agoro.

Comment: this would have been a go-to for me if i didnt have edited npm packages

Answer (score 0):

An option if you have edited npm packages, and thus would prefer to avoid deleting, re-installing, and re-editing said packages this is what worked for me:

`react-native start --reset-cache`